# setting variables in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following command:

```
echo "exec [loc_ver].[dbo].[sp_RptEmpCheckInOutMissingTime_2]" |
  /home/mdland_tool/common/bin/run_isql_prod_rpt_2.sh |
  grep "^| Row_2" |
  awk '{print $15 }'
```

which only works with `echo` in the front. I tried to set this line into a variable. I've tried quotations marks, parenthesis, and back ticks, with no luck.

May anyone tell me the correct syntax for setting this into a variable?

Comment: Are you trying to store the command itself in the variable, so you can execute it later, or are you trying to store the output of the command in the variable?

Comment: That's a really good question for me LOL

Comment: Please show me both, because there is a high chance of me running into  both situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more columns store in an array you should use this syntax (it is also good if you have only one result):

```
#!/bin/bash
result=( $( echo "exec [loc_ver].[dbo].[sp_RptEmpCheckInOutMissingTime_2]" |
/home/mdland_tool/common/bin/run_isql_prod_rpt_2.sh |
grep "^| Row_2" |
awk '{print $15 }' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=$(exec [loc_ver].[dbo].[sp_RptEmpCheckInOutMissingTime_2]" | /home/mdland_tool/common/bin/run_isql_prod_rpt_2.sh | grep "^| Row_2" | awk '{print $15 })
```

Comment: thanks for taking your precious time for the reply~ I got the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for [both meanings of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952113/setting-variables-in-bash-script?noredirect=1#comment22732290_15952113):

First, imagine a simpler case:

```
echo asdf
```

If you want to execute this command and store the result somewhere, you do the following:

```
$(echo asdf)
```

For example:

```
variable=$(echo asdf)
# or
if [ "$(echo asdf)" == "asdf" ]; then echo good; fi
```

So generally, `$(command)` executes `command` and returns the output.

If you want to store the text of the command itself, you can, well, just do that:

```
variable='echo asdf'
# or
variable="echo asdf"
# or
variable=echo\ asdf
```

Different formats depending on the content of your command. So now once you have the variable storing the command, you can simply execute the command with the `$(command)` syntax. However, pay attention that the command itself is in a variable. Therefore, you would execute the command by:

```
$($variable)
```

As a complete example, let's combine both:

```
command="echo asdf"
result=$($command)
echo $result
```